# Feed boolean value to a placeholder of type bool

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to set the `training` argument drop out in `tf.layers.dropout` to true/false based on my execution. below is the cod for the same

```
Train=tf.placeholder(tf.bool,shape=())

sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={X:X_inp,Y:Y_inp,Train: False })
```

but when i run the code get the following error.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype bool
         [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_BOOL, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

Tried to google the issue but could'nt get any help.

Answer (score 1):

I was a known bug in Tensorflow for a while, see [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7201). I suspect you're running an outdated version. Try updating.

Alternatively, you can try to fix it within this version. The issue is that the boolean tensor is not properly initialized. So you need to initialize it with a value when you run the general initializer. Somewhere in your code you run [`tf.global_variables_initializer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer) I suppose. Generally it's done in a fashion like this:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run( init )
```

In that line, insert `{ Train : True }` like `sess.run(init, { Train: True } )` to force initialization of the boolean tensor, and it should fix this too. (Idea from the issue referenced, haven't tested it.)

This should only be done once, after the graph has been set up but before you start running the training or inference.

Comment: I'm currently running 1.2.0 version of Tensorflow, also wanted should i be inserting the code suggested as
`sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={X:X_inp,Y:Y_inp,sess.run(Train: False) })`
or intitalize another variable to True/False and use it here?

Comment: Updated my answer with a more detailed description of the solution